How To Subract a Number Inside of a List Consecutively?
I want to subract a number inside of a list consecutively.
Let's say I have a list name A.
A = [6, 7, 9, 5]
Subtract 6 - 7, so it's -1. Then, subtract -1 - 9, it's -10. Then, subtract -10 - 5, it's -15.
It must use function.
list_number = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
def subtract(list_number):
    i = 0
    operate = list_number[i] - list_number[i+1]
return operate

But, this will only get the subtraction of "0" index number and "1" index number only. How to make the subtraction work consecutively?

You either need to write a loop or use a function that recurses over the index.

Use sum() to get the sum of the list except the first element (you can use a slice for this). Subtract that from the first element, and this is the result.

Is this an exercise where you are expected to use loops? If not, @Barmar has given you the answer I would use as well.

And if you have to use a loop, start by initializing the result variable to list_number[0]. Then loop over the rest of the list, subtracting the element from the variable.

@JonSG Needlessly overflows for [1e308] * 3, though.

@nocomment That strikes me more like Is floating point math broken? than a weakness of that strategy.

@JonSG I disagree. If done as specified, all calculations are exact and there's no issue. It's the strategy that causes the problem.

@nocomment is print(-1e309) then correct according to your criteria or is it a floating point issue?

@JonSG I'd say "Both."

@nocomment Overflow is going to be an issue for the addition of any arbitrary sequence of floats, regardless of sign. Unless you are suggesting the OP do an analysis of the entire input set before adding to determine which, if any, sequence of operations will avoid overflow, I'd say it's not worth worrying about here.

@chepner I'm not worrying, just wanted to point out it's not 100% equivalent. Probably something like [0.1, 0.2, 0.3] would've shown a difference as well, [1e308] * 3 was just the simpler example.

Using functools reduce.
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x, y: x-y, [6, 7, 9, 5])


Go two steps further: subtract = partial(reduce, sub)

(sub being a function you import from the operator module.)

As kindly alluded to in the comment, the logic of your function can use the various properties of addition and subtraction, whereby subtracting each value yields the same result as subtracting the sum of values.
For example:
def fn1():
    a = [6, 7, 9, 5]
    return (a[0] - sum(a[1:]))

Output:
>>> fn1()
-15

Subtract the sum of the list (except the first value) from the first value. The first value is isolated using slicing; both in the forms of 'only the fist value' ([0]) and 'everything after the first value' ([1:]).

If however, you wanted to use an explicit loop - it can look something like this, albeit slightly more messy to look at:
def fn2():
    a = [6, 7, 9, 5]
    sum_ = a[0]
    for i in a[1:]:
        sum_ -= i
    return sum_

Output:
>>> fn2()
-15

This works similarly by isolating the first element into a variable called sum_, then subtracting each following element in turn, using a[1:] as before. In case you aren't aware, the sum_ -= i operator combination is the same as sum_ = sum_ - i, just more concise.

Subtraction isn't commutative. Addition is, but you don't use the fact that x + y == y + x here. You use associativity to assert that x + y + z == x + (y + z). Couple that with additive inverses and the distributive property, you can state that 6 - 9 - 7 - 5 == 6 + -9 + -7 + -5 == 6 + (-9 + -7 + -5) == 6 - (9 + 7 + 5).

@chepner - Well stated, thank you.  My oversimplification was misleading and inaccurate.  I’ll update this more in depth later; thank you.

@chepner I don't see distributivity, either. What are the two binary operations involved?

Distributivity is what lets you pull a factor of -1 from the parenthesized group, so that we're subtracting a positive sum rather than adding a negative sum to the first number. (Even more explicitly, 6 + (-9 + -7 + -5) == 6 + (-1*9 + -1*7 + -1*5) == 6 + -1  * (9 + 7 + 5) == 6 - (9 + 7 + 5)).

(Ugh. Ignore my consistent reordering of the original sequence 6, 7, 9, 5 to 6, 9, 7, 5.)

@chepner Ah, if you introduce *. Good.
